# How to use GPUs with tensorflow．

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

In `device_lib.list_local_devices()`, GPUs are listed, but not in `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')`. How can I enable the use of GPUs?

When I run the following code

```
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

```
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 7653367915632035543
, name: "/device:XLA_CPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_CPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 3963066801636466049
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_CPU device"
, name: "/device:XLA_GPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_GPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 17673092428858454380
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_GPU device"
]
```

GPU is exist, but do following code

```
print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))
```

```
[]
```

GPU is not recognized.

Comment: What OS are you running on? GPU support for vanilla Windows was dropped in version 2.12, but should be available if you install Python and Tensorflow into WSL2 and run it there.

Comment: The device is actually called XLA_GPU, as you can see in your logs.

Comment: windows10
tensorflow2.3.0
cuDNN 7.6.5
CUDA 10.1

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by updating the NVIDIA driver.